# Can I find out the renaming history of a user in a post's context (or in general)?

Tags: discussion, support, display-names

In my opinion it's getting harder to distinguish who is/was talking to whom lately.

It can be pretty confusing (and it's not really comfortable) to follow a thread of *Alice* - known as *Bob* until yesterday - answering to a comment/post originated by *Fred*, who has changed his/her name to *Dharma* four weeks ago, created and deleted a comment under that name, and changed the name again to *Sally* the day before yesterday and commenting again.

This is just a hypothetical example, but you know what I mean.

Can I find out the renaming history of a user in a post's context (or in general)?

How am I supposed to easily follow threads with massive name changes (and/or comment deletions)?

Comment: [As seen on the Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26518)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I really feel kinda _welbog_'ed^^

Comment: It'd be nice if the comment contraption would update the names to match the current names. :)

Comment: Related: [Make the “past names” list public info for 30 days after changing your name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-for-30-days-after-changing-your-name).

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is not a forum. Comments are generally not intended to be... necessary information. Therefore, exactly who said what to whom is not considered important information. The primary purpose of the @-stuff is to be able to notify someone that you're responding to them, so that they can get the information you're trying to give them. That someone can come along a few weeks later and get something from it is more or less unimportant.

Comment: If comments don't serve any historical/traceable purpose, why are they still there, even after months of inactivity? I can't believe, that the SE team would keep tons of "clutter" for no reason. MSO is a place with much discussion in the comments. Even on SO, I more often than not need the comments to understand how a post has evolved from question to solution. And to know who wrote what, helps me to build mental pictures of people I don't know in real life, but only in virtuality.

Comment: @JürgenThelen: There's a difference between "useless" and "not necessary".

Comment: yes, I'm aware of this difference^^. But if it's really _"more or less unimportant, if someone can still get something from it a few weeks later"_, then you and me may just have different opinions about what the point of SE sites is. For me it's to build free, wiki-style knowledge bases, for current _and_ for already solved problems. If it's really only thought to handle current/unsolved problems (kind of hotline), I completely misunderstood that point.

Comment: @JürgenThelen: Except that you can't edit comments. So you can't build "wiki-style knowledge bases" on *comments*. What matters on SE sites are questions and answers. Everything else is not the point.

Comment: Hm, I wasn't talking about editing comments, but using comments to track how a post evolved for current _and_ already solved problems. I thought that emphasis on _and_ was clear. Otoh I'm not a native speaker, so maybe my phrasing just sucks. Nevermind, your pov seems to be, that comments on posts older than a few weeks don't necessarily need to be understood anymore; as long as there is a question and answers, everything's fine. So we simply disagree. I'm ok with that.