# Accessing Topics of Interest

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I became active user on Stackoverflow few months ago. Slowly i discovered in Stackexchange other interesting forums. Now I have no time to take a look at all.
Is there any way to see the hot topics of the forums that i like?
For me, it would be a way to access invaluable information that would otherwise go unnoticed.

### EDIT: due answer

> > .. of the forums that i like?
>
> No. There is no build-in way to filter hot questions.

Seeing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stackexchange-and-stac), I found a way to achieve what I want.

I think this feature would add a functionality very useful. So, feature-request tagged. Dreaming is free.

Comment: @Community SE would take into account a feature request? or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to see the hot topics...

Yes. They are located [there](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot).
Also, some of hot question are shown below the "Hot Network Questions" title (it is clickable and will take you to the link I already provided), on the right side:

[image]

> ... of the forums that i like?

No. There is no build-in way to filter hot questions.

Comment: Suggest replacing the verb with idiom "built-in". ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232424/165773